# Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT for Dell Precision 5820

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my workstation tower. I need a dual boot for Windows and Ubuntu.

When I boot from my USB drive, and the grub list appears for Ubuntu installation, selecting either install Ubuntu or try Ubuntu without installing leads to a dark screen , throwing the error mentioned in headline.

I have tried all the solutions as listed here for this issue, however, nothing works. 
I have tried:

1. changing UEFI to legacy and back to uefi
2. disabled fast boot
3. created my bootable drive as per Ubuntu instructions using Rufus
4. turned off secure boot

I am currently running windows enterprise, as this is my office workstation.